# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException exception in my query

Tags: exception

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException exception in my query

This my query it inserts properly but shows exception

```
sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO requiredfiles (id, scheduleid, layoutid, status, name, priority,size,checksum) VALUES ('"+ media_id+ "', '"+ scheduleid+ "', '"+ layoutid+ "', '0', '" + url + "', '" + priority + "', '" + size + "', '" + checksum + "');");
```

Comment: It should be nice if you wrote the complete error message.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed -- this is my error -- thanks for ur replay

Comment: Could you also the creation script of your table and the values you try to enter?

Comment: i am get value from json and inserting in table

Comment: Yep but the table exists. What's its structure. Are the non nullable fields?

Comment: yes table  field is non null

Comment: There is no field called table! This fields I see are id, scheduleid, layoutid, status, name, priority,size and checksum

Comment: requiredfiles is a table name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35066/discussion-between-c-champagne-and-neelaganda-moorthy)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I already write this despite the lack of information. This error means that a constraint has been violated. It is possible possible that you are inserting a null value into a field that cannot be null or that you intent to set a value to an auto incremental field.

Without knowing anything about the table and the value of the variables, it is impossible to answer more precisely to the question.

[Here](http://vkedco.blogspot.be/2012/08/three-fixes-to-sqliteconstraintexceptio.html) you can find some tips on how to fix this.